Expand product of sums to nested sum
Good day
I have this product of two sums
expr = Sum[(2 n + 3) a[n] Exp[I p n x], {n, c, d}] Sum[
   Exp[I q n x] b[n], {n, e, f}]

And I want to expand it to a nested sum
expr = Sum[(2 m + 3) a[m] Exp[I p m x]
   Exp[I q n x] b[n], {m, c, d}, {n, e, f}]

I already tried Expand, ExpandAll, Simplify, FullSimplify, and I tried
expr /. Sum[a__[m__], {m__, c__, d__}] Sum[
    b__[n__], {n__, e__, f__}] :> Sum[a[m] b[n], {m, c, d}, {n, e, f}]
Collect[expr, Exp[I x]]
FourierTrigSeries[expr, x, 3]

None of it seems to work.
Thanks in advance!
Boudewijn Verhaar

I suspect there is a typo in expr. Consider: Sum[(2 m + 3) a[m] Exp[I p n x], {m, c, d}] Sum[   Exp[I q n x] b[n], {n, e, f}]

Are you referring to the name of the summation variable? In that case: one is free to rename a summation variable, as long as it is done consistently. Since a summation variable is a "local" variable, with its scope limited to the summation. The n in the first summation can be replaced by m, it is equivalent.

You have to name the summation variables differently in the two sums to work properly.
sum = Sum[(2 m + 3) a[m] Exp[I p m x], {m, c, d}] Sum[Exp[I q n x] b[n], {n, e, f}];
sum /. Sum[x_, y_] Sum[p_, q_] :> Sum[x p, q, y]



Or if both sums use the same summation variable then you have to replace one of them in a quite cumbersome way.
sum = Sum[(2 n + 3) a[n] Exp[I p n x], {n, c, d}] Sum[Exp[I q n x] b[n], {n, e, f}];
sum /. (Sum[x_, y_]) Sum[p_, q_] :> Sum[x (p /. n -> m), Evaluate[q /. n -> m], y]



